# How does "as" clause affect "import" in Python?

Tags: python

I thought that "as" clause just makes an alias of an imported module. 
However, "import" fails with "as" clause in the following code.

```py
import tensorflow.python.eager as eager
```

This statement raises the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/snippet/prof/importer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.eager as eager
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

When I remove the "as" clause, the "import" successes.
How does "as" clause affect the success and failure of "import"?

Comment: `from tensorflow.python import eager`?

Comment: Or ```from tensorflow.python import eager as egr```, perhaps?

Comment: as is used for using an alias. But u are using the alias as same as class name. Try using another alias like ea or something.

Comment: ```import tensorflow.python.eager as ea``` raises the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tensorflow.python import eager
```

imports the name "**tensorflow.python**" and then gets its attribute `eager`, whereas

```
import tensorflow.python.eager as eager
```

imports the name "**tensorflow**", and in there tries to find the attribute `python`, and from that the attribute `eager`, which it should then put in your global namespace as `eager`. And that's a huge difference, since there is no object `python` in tensorflow's `__init__.py`, which is what represents the tensorflow package when imported and which does not know about any subpackages that might exist. Therefore the error

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

Comment: Thanks. As you say, tensorflow module doesn't have object "python" (which have been deleted). 

However I have not understood why "import tensorflow.python.eager" doesn't raises the error. Does "as" clause change the previous path from a directory path to an attribute?

Comment: `import tensorflow.python.eager` treats the whole thing as the import name, same as the `from .. import` syntax above. Which is why this can only be used to import modules or packages, not "attributes" of those like classes or functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have ".eager" while importing to import "eager" as something.

Try this, it will work fine:

```
from tensorflow.python import eager as eager
```

Comment: Your example works fine, but I have not understood how my example is wrong. The following code is valid 

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

So using "as" clause with import is not illegal.

Comment: What you did with "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" is perfect. But if you do the same thing what you did in your question, then it will look like this: "from matplotlib.plot import plot as plt". Now this will throw an error. 
So if you plan to import "plot" do not have it as ".plot" and then again have plot following that, as that will throw an error. This is what I pointed out in the answer

Comment: What is the difference between the pyplot case and the eager case? Is the difference whether the last element of the imported path is a directory or not?

Comment: The difference is if you wanna import eager as eager or anything else, don't write "from tesorflow.python.eager" but write "from tensorflow.python import eager as eager". As you can see above there is no ".eager".
Similarly in matplotlib case if you want to import plot as plt or anything else do not write "from matplotlib.plot import plot". This will throw an error. Insted write "from matplotlib import plot as plt"